# Is it possible to censor a transaction in Monero?

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures, transaction-data

Would it not be impossible to do censor because of how ring signatures work and not knowing what a transaction is for or where it is going? maybe i am missing something. thanks

Comment: As currently worded this looks like a duplicate. Also, there is no need to say "thanks" each time you ask a question.

Comment: ah ok, nothing came up in the search for 'censoring transactions' thanks for the linked answer :))